# Bootstrap column on mobile positions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the views like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-9">mymaincontent</>
    <div class="col-md-12">mygallery</>
    <div class="col-md-3">mysidebar</>
</>
```

I want to make my sidebar stay ontop on my desktop view 
and make my gallery stay above sidebar on my mobile view

Comment: Please show us your HTML

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try CSS Flexbox : [A complete guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), since it's the easiest way to dynamically modify content positon.

Thanks to [CSS Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) you should test the max width of the viewport :

```
//Default style
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

//Adaptative style
@media (max-width: 12450px) {
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column; /*from row to column*/
    }
}
```